# Ordering a string alphabetically - did I miss something obvious?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class Anagram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "Despera tion-".toLowerCase();
        String b = "A Rope Ends It".toLowerCase();

        String aSorted = sortStringAlphabetically(a);
        String bSorted = sortStringAlphabetically(b);

        if(aSorted.equals(bSorted)){
            System.out.println("Anagram Found!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No anagram was found");
        }

    }

    public static String sortStringAlphabetically(String s) {

        char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
        int cnt = 0;
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(ca[cnt])) 
                al.add(ca[cnt]);

            cnt++;
        }

        Collections.sort(al);
        return al.toString();
    }
}
```

As a learner, I hacked up this boolean Anagram checker.  My chosen solution was to create a sortStringAlphabetically method seems to do just too much type-juggling String -> chars[] -> ArrayList ->String - given that I do just want to compare 2 strings to test whether one phrase is an anagram of another - could I have done it with less type-juggling?

ps The tutors solution was a mile away from my attempt, and probably much better for a lot of reasons - but I am really trying to get a handle on all the different Collection types.

http://www.home.hs-karlsruhe.de/~pach0003/informatik_1/aufgaben/en/doc/src-html/de/hska/java/exercises/arrays/Anagram.html#line.18

EDIT

FTW here is the original challenge, I realise I wandered away from the solution.

http://www.home.hs-karlsruhe.de/~pach0003/informatik_1/aufgaben/en/arrays.html

My initial kneejerk reaction was to simply work though array a, knocking out those chars which matched with array b - but that seemingly required me to rebuild the array at every iteration - Many thanks for all your efforts to educate me.

Comment: pretty sure the instructors anagram marker fails if the string is 258 characters.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: no - but it will fail if the string contains any characters outside the Latin1 character set

Comment: Two comments (well 3): 
1) You're trying to manage two counters in your method. Think about why you're doing that and if you need it.
2) If you're trying to learn types read the documentation on String, it has position indexes as a method so you can avoid the array.
2.5) You probably want to focus on the basic array solution. Collections are great, but they are inefficient for CS classes most of the time and they won't help you with BigO unless you're writing them from scratch.

Comment: @Cups: the solution you linked to is definitely **not** solving the same problem as your solution.  Your solution works for every Unicode letter considered to be a "letter" by Java's *Character.isLetter* method.  The other solution only works for "strings" made of characters in the 0-255 range and only excludes white spaces.  It is trivial to rewrite the other solution in Java, but you have to know you're definitely not solving the exact same thing.  So, as always, *the* eternal question is:  *"What are the exact requirements?"*

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt ah yes I see that now, forgot that chars have int values :(

Comment: Instead of creating an ArrayList, cant the Arrays.Sort() method be used for sorting..!!

Comment: @Vijay - thanks, yes that is my one of my main take-aways.

Comment: @DanielChapman focusing on the pure array solution, yes, you are right -- that is what I would like to do... I find it too dazzling to see all these collections -- got to get a grip on the fundamentals. Thx.

Comment: @Cups if you have the time and want to learn it, take the time to do both. Generics take a little time to grasp, mainly due to the syntax, but they save time in large projects. Good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to improve this, if you go with this algorithm.
First, you don't necessarily need to create a character array. You can use String.charAt() to access a specific character of your string.

Second, you don't need a list. If you used a SortedMultiSet or a SortedBag, you could just add things in sorted order. If you write a function that creates the SortedMultiSet from your string, you could just compare the sets without rebuilding the string.

Note: I don't know what libraries you're allowed to use (Google and Apache have these types), but you can always 'brew your own'.

Also, make sure to use generics for your types. Just defining ArrayLists is pretty risky, IMHO.

Comment: Use generics - of course... I don't yet have the immediate reaction to do this - something I should endeavour to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm, but shorter (and yet, slower). The "type-juggling" is done "implicitly" in Java's various library classes:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
      a.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\W", "").split("")));
    List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
      b.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\W", "").split("")));

    Collections.sort(listA);
    Collections.sort(listB);

    return listA.equals(listB);
}
```

Optionally, replace the `\W` regular expression to exclude those letters that you don't want to consider for the anagram

Answer (score 1):

You could just sort the string without using a list:

```
public static String sortStringAlphabetically(String s) {
    String lettersOnly = s.replaceAll("\\W", "");
    char[] chars = lettersOnly.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

N.B. I haven't actually tried running the code.

Comment: Code works fine :) - much simpler too, I had not realized I could use sort so simply -- believing it had to be done on a Collection derived from from an abstract List. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Anagram {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s1 = "Despera tion-";
        String s2 = "A Rope Ends It";
        anagramCheck(s1, s2);
    }

    private static void anagramCheck(String s1, String s2) {
        if (isAnagram(s1, s2)) {
            System.out.println("Anagram Found!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No anagram was found");
        }
    }

    private static boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
        return sort(s1).equals(sort(s2));
    }

    private static String sort(String s) {
        char[] array = s.replaceAll("\\W", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(array);
        return new String(array);
    }
}
```